# Time complexity of travel a trie

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, nodes, trie

Would it be O(26n) where 26 is the number of letters of the alphabet and n is the number of levels of the trie? For example this is the code to print a trie:

```
public void print() 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
    {
        if(this.next[i] != null) 
        {
            this.next[i].print();
        }
    }
    if(this.word != null) 
    {
        System.out.println(this.word.getWord());
    }
}
```

So watching this code makes me think that my aproximation of the time complexity is correct in the worst of the cases that would be the 26 nodes full for n levels.

Comment: Number 26 is a constant, it doesn't depend on the size of the data, therefore it should be ignored in the O notation.

Comment: A remark on landau notation: There is no `O(26n)`. Since `26` is a constant, it would be `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be O(26n) where 26 is the number of letters of the alphabet and n is the number of levels of the trie?

No.  Each node in the trie must be visited, and O(1) work performed for each one (ignoring the work attributable to processing the children, which is accounted separately).  The number of children does not matter on a per-node basis, as long as it is bounded by a constant (e.g. 26).

How many nodes are there altogether?  Generally more than the number of words stored in the trie, and possibly a lot more.  For a naively-implemented, perfectly balanced, complete trie with n levels below the root, each level has 26 times as many nodes as the previous, and so the total number of nodes is 1 + 26 + 26<sup>2</sup> + ... + 26<sup>n</sup>.  That is O(26<sup>n+1</sup>) == O(26<sup>n</sup>) == O(2<sup>n</sup>), or "exponential" in the number of levels, which also corresponds to the length of the longest word stored within.

But one is more likely to be interested in measuring the complexity in terms of the number of words stored in the trie.  With a careful implementation, it is possible to have nodes only for those words and for each maximal initial substring that is common to two or more of those words.  In that event, every node has either zero children or at least two, so for *w* total words, the total number of nodes is bounded by *w* + *w*/2 + *w*/4 + ..., which converges to 2*w*.  Therefore, a traversal of a trie with those structural properties costs O(2*w*) == O(*w*).

Moreover, with a little more thought, it is possible to conclude that the particular structural property I described is not really necessary to have O(*w*) traversal.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with a trie but the big O notation is mainly to depict approximately how quickly the running time or resource consumption grows relative to the input size. The way I think of it is just rereferring to general shape of the curve on the graph rather than exact points on the graph. A O(1) looks like a flat line, while a O(n) looks like a line at a 45 deg angle, etc.

[image: common complexities]
source: https://medium.com/dataseries/how-to-calculate-time-complexity-with-big-o-notation-9afe33aa4c46

Now for the algorithm in the question. I am not familiar with a trie, but at first glace I would say it is O(1) (constant time), because the number of iterations of the loop is constant (always 26). However, in the loop it has `this.next[i].print()` which could completely change the answer depending on *its* complexity, and uncovers a important question we need to know: what is `n`?.

I am going to assume that the `this.next[i]` is of the same type as `this`, making the `this.next[i].print()` kind of a recursive call. In such a scenario the time it takes to finish executing will all depend on the number of instances that will have to be iterated though (visited). This algorithm resembles [Depth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) but does not safe guard against infinite recursion. This may be based on some additional information known about the `next[i]` instances (nodes) such as an instance is only ever referenced by at most 1 other instance. In this case the runtime complexity would be on order of `O(n)` where `n` is the number of instances or nodes.

... assuming that the `this.word.getWord()` runs in constant time as well. If it depends on some other word input, the runtime may as well be `O(n * w)` where `n` is number of nodes and `w` is the size of the words.

Comment: The number of iterations of the loop is fixed *per invocation of `print()`*, but the method is recursive, so that does not by itself tell you much about the total amount of work.

Comment: John, feel free to edit my answer if its not clear but that is exactly what I have pointed out. To find the actual run time complexity we need more context -- what are the actual 'inputs'.